# Android Library using Main Project Resources

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a library for Android projects.

The activity is declared in the library project, as it will be reusable in different projects. This activity is using images which are project specific. I have added those images in the main project.

How can I access resources from the main project in the library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put a copy of all relevant resources in the library. It's perfectly legal. If you want to override them in the actual app, you can. If the IDs clash, the end product will use the resources from the app.

EDIT: the alternative is filesystem-level links. On Windows, use `mklink` to create hardlinks to your resource folders in the project; on *nix, use `ln`. This may mess up your source control, if any, so proceed with caution.

Comment: This may work, but there's bound to be a better solution.. Copying all resources isn't really viable if you want to reference a lot of large images for example :/

Comment: It is not necessary to copy all resources; you can just put an empty file in the library project and override that file with the real resource file of the same name in each app that uses the library project.  At least, this works if you are loading the resources from code, and I think it would work otherwise, as well.  The blank file will never be accessed so long as it is overridden in each app with a real resource file of the same name, but its presence will allow the library to compile.