# Refer an image resource(of main project) in library project

Tags: android, image, resources, refer

I want to use image resource of my main project in the library project.
Suppose that I do have an image "abc.png" in my Main project and i want to refer it in my library project. Is there a way to do it.
I cannot copy the images in the library project as I am using the same library project for other projects too referencing different images.

Comment: Uh, doesn't tying it via hard coded images to the main project defeat the purpose of a library project?

Comment: I want to use different images in different projects. Code is same. I think it might be a better use of library project

Comment: Then pass the resource id to the library at runtime from the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put an empty file in the library project and override that file with the real resource file of the same name in each app that uses the library project.

Refer to this answer link  [Android Library using Main Project Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036895/1441666)

Comment: I thought of that but isn't there any better answer.