# Android Gradle referencing styles from dependent module

Tags: resources, dependency-management, android-gradle-plugin

so I have an Android project in Android Studio (0.6.1). There are 2 Modules **A** and **B**. **A** is my main-module and it depends on **B** which includes various resources (drawables, strings, styles) and therefore functions as something like a library (although it is no library-project). I added **B** as git-subtree, included it in my settings.gradle and building works fine.

**Now there is a problem:** I want to reference resources from **B** in **A**. For drawables I already found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036746/android-library-using-main-project-resources/4036895#4036895) that I can just create dummy resources in **A** that will be overridden by **B**. But unfortunately that **doesn't work for styles**, that are defined in **B**. The dummies I create in styles.xml in **A** are not overwritten.

My aim is to define multiple styles in **B** like:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle1" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/buttonorange</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
<style name="ButtonStyle2" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/buttonorange</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

And then back in **A** I want to have the opportunity to choose wether to apply ButtonStyle1 or ButtonStyle like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle1</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle2</item>
</style>
```

But when I do this, I always get 
`Error:(5, 42) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:buttonStyle' with value '@style/ButtonStyle1').`

All in all I guess that my gradle configuration itself is correct because overriding drawables works fine already. **So what am I doing wrong - how can I reference styles defined in B in A?**

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app', ':uiframework:uiframework'
```

**build.gradle from A**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.uiframeworkexample'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':uiframework:uiframework')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you apply correct plugin for your B(library) project at build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```